# Inject a test resource (.xml file) into a test class by @Value and Resource type in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I have a `product.xml` file I want to have 'injected' easily into my test class by using the `@Value` annotation of Spring.

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "test.file.product=product.xml"
})
public class XmlToJsonParserTest {

  @Value("${test.file.product}")
  private Resource product;

  @Autowired
  private XmlToJsonParser xlToJsonParser;

  @Test
  public void shouldParseFromXml() throws IOException {
    JsonNode node = xmlToJsonParser.getNodeFromXML(product.getFile());
    assertThat(node).isNotNull();
  }
}
```

My testfile is under `src/test/resources/product.xml`
I managed to get that working before but just can't figure out how I did it or what setup I had back the day.

**In this case `product` is always `null`**

Comment: did you try adding the `test.file.product` in application properties of the test/resource folder

Comment: Without `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class` the Spring based annotations won't do anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum legend